# JSON from Google Places

Tags: android, json, google-places-api, google-places

Here I want to get the types of a specific place using Google Places API, but Im obviously having a huge problem with how to get the desired value of "types" from the JSON format.

here is what I tried to do

```
 JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); 
             JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions.getString("results"));
            JSONArray types = ( (JSONObject)ja.get(0)).getJSONArray("types");
             for (int i = 0; i < types.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
               //here I stop  
            }
```

and this is the JSON response

```
"results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "529 Kent Street, Sydney NSW, Australia",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8750460,
               "lng" : 151.2052720
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "827f1ac561d72ec25897df088199315f7cbbc8ed",
         "name" : "Tetsuya's",
         "rating" : 4.30,
         "reference" : "CnRmAAAAmmm3dlSVT3E7rIvwQ0lHBA4sayvxWEc4nZaXSSjRtfKRGoYnfr3d5AvQGk4e0u3oOErXsIJwtd3Wck1Onyw6pCzr8swW4E7dZ6wP4dV6AsXPvodwdVyqHgyGE_K8DqSp5McW_nFcci_-1jXb5Phv-RIQTzv5BjIGS0ufgTslfC6dqBoU7tw8NKUDHg28bPJlL0vGVWVgbTg",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
      },
```

so would you please help me figure out a solution to this problem? Thank you

Comment: What is the whole JSON format that you get after making a call to the Google Places API? Is that what you get in response? It would be helpful in answering if you post that. Also have you tried seeing other questions where people have tried to parse JSON responses? It would definitely help you.

Comment: yes I've been searching here for a while now, and I didn't reach a useful solution.

Comment: I've edited the post with the JSON response that I want to parse

Comment: can you post url which you are calling ?

Comment: URL googlePlaces = new URL(
                        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(place, "UTF-8") +
                        "&sensor=true&key=key");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String testData = "{\"results\" : [ "
            + "{\"formatted_address\" : \"529 Kent Street, Sydney NSW, Australia\", "
            + "\"geometry\" : {"
            + "\"location\" : {"
            + "\"lat\" : -33.8750460,"
            + "\"lng\" : 151.2052720}"
            + "},"
            + "\"icon\" : \"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png\","
            + "\"id\" : \"827f1ac561d72ec25897df088199315f7cbbc8ed\", "
            + "\"name\" : \"Tetsuya's\","
            + "\"rating\" : 4.30,"
            + "\"reference\" : \"CnRmAAAAmmm3dlSVT3E7rIvwQ0lHBA4sayvxWEc4nZaXSSjRtfKRGoYnfr3d5AvQGk4e0u3oOErXsIJwtd3Wck1Onyw6pCzr8swW4E7dZ6wP4dV6AsXPvodwdVyqHgyGE_K8DqSp5McW_nFcci_-1jXb5Phv-RIQTzv5BjIGS0ufgTslfC6dqBoU7tw8NKUDHg28bPJlL0vGVWVgbTg\", "
            + "\"types\" : [ \"restaurant\", \"food\", \"establishment\" ] "
            + "}] }";
    JSONObject predictions;
    try {
        predictions = new JSONObject(testData);
        JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) predictions.get("results");
        JSONArray types = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) ja.get(0)).get("types");
        String result = types.toString();
        result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 1);
        String[] allTypes = result.split(",");
        for(int i = 0; i < allTypes.length;i++) {
            String type = allTypes[i];
            //save your type
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: yes this is my problem! I don't know how to extract the Strings from these JSONObjects provided that I can't say Jo.getString() because I don't know the types sent to me from google

Answer (score 0):

```
//Supposing that you get the complete response as one JSONObject called 'res' as follows:

JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
try {
    res = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString()); // stringBuilder is string which you append everthing when you are reading the stream
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can extract the values corresponding to 'types' from the resulting 'res' JSON Object as follows:

```
JSONObject type;
String type_string;
try {
    type = ret.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0);
    type_string = type.getString("types");
    Log.d("test", "formattted address:" + location_string);

} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();

}
```

In 'type_string' you should have the value string which is in front of 'types', i.e 
something like:

> ["restaurant", "food", "establishment"]

Then you can use .Split() function to split the String using "," as the delimiter. Something like :

```
String[] str_array = type_string.split(",");
String stringa = str_array[0]; 
String stringb = str_array[1];
String stringC = str_array[2];
```

The above str_array will store the type strings.

P.S: I've not run this code. I just wanted to give you an idea how to approach your problem. You might need to tweak few things to fit into your existing code. Hope it helps.